# Auth::attempt() always return true in laravel 5.1

Tags: authentication, laravel-5

I am wondering why my condition is not working. If I remove the `password_reset` then it work, but when I include, it won't work again. Please see my code below:

```
$requirements = [
    'username' => $request->input('username'),
    'password' => $request->input('password'),
    'deleted' => 0,
    'status' => 1,
    'confirmed' => 1,
    'password_reset' => 0
];


    if(Auth::attempt($requirements)){
        dd('success');
    } else{
        return redirect()->back()->with('danger', 'Oops! Login Failed.');
    }
```

Comment: Do you have `password_reset` in your User table ?

Comment: @Maraboc Yes bro. I have already include it.

Comment: And `attempt` method return `true` even if you pass a wrong password ?? or what's the exact problem ?

Comment: @Maraboc The only problem is, I just want to add the `password_reset` and its always logging the user in even the user's `password_reset` = 1.

Comment: Remove `password_reset` from `requirements` and try this work around `if(Auth::attempt($requirements) && ! auth()->user()->password_reset){
    dd('success');
} else{
    return redirect()->back()->with('danger', 'Oops! Login Failed.');
}`

Comment: @Maraboc I will try it later. But I'm just wondering why my code is not working?  Do you have any idea?

Comment: I don't know the why !! by the way wath is the type of `password_reset` in the database ?

Comment: It's TINYINT type.